# Is it possible to extend org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.*Template class(es)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

Although the current version (1.0.3) of **Spring Social Facebook** provides operations for me to start with, there's still a few other Graph API calls which are not implemented; such as getting the albums from a fan page, and it just so happens to be a crucial part of the project I'm working on.

I want to add methods to org.springframework.social.facebook.api.**Page** class which in fact make the not-yet-implemented Graph API calls. After looking up the source codes, I've figured out the magic actually happens in org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.**PageTemplate** class. As the principle of not reinventing the wheel, I'd like to write a new class and I plan on extending the PageTemplate class, but it won't: the *Code Completion* feature of the IDE shows up only **FacebookTemplate** for me to extend. Somehow my instinct tells me it ain't there. According to what I've observed from Github, Maven (tree expanded), **PageTemplate** class does exist alrite.

Is there any reason why I can't extend it, or better/smarter/possible approaches, perhaps!?

Comment: Maybe PageTemplate is created on the fly by Spring...

Comment: On the fly? Meaning like how the Spring JPA Repository works!?

Answer (score 0):

`org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.PageTemplate` is not a final class so it can be extended without a problem.

Your inability to find the class suggests you're looking at the wrong dependency. Have a look at spring-social-facebook

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

The [`PageTemplate` class on GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-facebook/blob/master/spring-social-facebook/src/main/java/org/springframework/social/facebook/api/impl/PageTemplate.java)

Comment: I have both spring-social and spring-social-facebook in my pom.xml; but thanx anywayz...